# best way redirect/reload pages in PHP

Tags: php, redirect, reload

Whats the best way to reload/redirect a page in PHP which completely removes all history/cache? Which headers should I use?

What happens:

On clicking a link, get-parameters is set and a script is executed. When finished, I want to redirect and reload the page without the get-parameters. At first, it looks like nothing has happened, but when pressing F5, the changes appear.

What I want:

Redirect and reload so the changes appear without pressing F5.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Which page do you want not to turn up in the history? The one you are calling from, or the one you are redirecting to? Same goes for the cache.

Answer (score 27):

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/', true, 302);
exit;
```

Ref: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

edit:

> This response is only cacheable if
>   indicated by a Cache-Control or
>   Expires header field.

Comment: This is just what I needed, I was doing something completely different to this question but the answer worked great :)

Comment: better to use:

    header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/', true, 302);
    exit;

Answer (score 24):

```
function redirect($url) {
    if(!headers_sent()) {
        //If headers not sent yet... then do php redirect
        header('Location: '.$url);
        exit;
    } else {
        //If headers are sent... do javascript redirect... if javascript disabled, do html redirect.
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";';
        echo '</script>';
        echo '<noscript>';
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$url.'" />';
        echo '</noscript>';
        exit;
    }
}

// How to use
$url = "www.google.com";
redirect($url);
```

Comment: Thanks @Phill for this answer. You saved me a whole lot of time with this function.

Comment: Hm. I believe that the coder should decide what type to redirect he wants to use in a given situation, not rely on a function to choose for him. E.g. if you want a HTTP request via `location`, then you should make sure that headers weren't sent yet, rather than use fallbacks in if they were. That's how I think at least

Answer (score 7):

The best way to reload a page and force it to be not taken from the cache will be to append a random id or timestamp to the end of the url as querystring. It makes the request unique each time.

Comment: It can be the best way, it's strange to do this.
Imagine: www.google.com.br?randomId=12381289371

The best way should be send appropriated headers.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
echo '<script>document.location.replace("someurl.php");</script>';
```

This should replace browser history but not cache.

Answer (score 1):

```
header('Location: http://example.com/path/to/file');
```

Answer (score 1):

just for information, related to SEO:

301 would tell search engine to replace url in their index. so if url1 is redirecting to url2 with 301, all major search engine [google, yahoo + bing] would replace url1 with url2.

302 works in different way. It says the url is located `temporarily` in some other address.

[see this post](http://www.bigoakinc.com/blog/when-to-use-a-301-vs-302-redirect/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: no-store, private, no-cache, must-revalidate');     // HTTP/1.1
header('Cache-Control: pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0, max-stale = 0', false);  // HTTP/1.1
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');                  // Date in the past  
header('Expires: 0', false); 
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
header ('Pragma: no-cache');
header("Location: https://example.com", true, 302);
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way is to use a Header Redirect

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/', true, 302);
exit;
```

But beware, that it has to be sent BEFORE any other output is sent to the browser.